# From Googlesheet send a whatsapp with Twilio api

Tags: api, google-apps-script, twilio, message, whatsapp

Good morning to all of you.
*I need your invaluable help.*
Unfortunately I don't understand much about programming :-(

I would like to understand if it is possible through Google App Script to create the following:

I have a google spreadsheet where customers register by entering their phone number.
At each new registration (each new line) the script automatically sends a whatsapp message to the customer indicating that the registration was successful.

I have TWILIO and its API as an active service.
I have activated a specific number and everything is verified and working.

I ask for your help as I just don't know where to start.
Thanks to everyone and I hope to receive your advice.
Mauro

---

**Update:**

I'm trying to do it with ZAPIER also seeing a post created some time ago:
[How to send a whatsapp message through twilio via zapier webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58486687/how-to-send-a-whatsapp-message-through-twilio-via-zapier-webhook/66477686)

But I have this error:
The request could not be sent to Webhooks by Zapier. The app returned "A 'To' phone number is required.".

I have attached the image with the inserted configuration. Where did I go wrong? How should I correct it?

[image]

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can follow this blog which seems to offer similar functionality - https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html.

Comment: @Alan Thank you for your answer.
Is this code also valid for sending a message with WHATSAPP?
Because I only find SMS written.

I have a verified number for WHATSAPP.

Comment: In your Zapier screenshot, your To number says "Numero di telefono: _No data_". It seems that you are perhaps not sending any data. as the To number.

Comment: @ philnash thanks for your intervention.
I tried to put the data but it always gives me the usual error :-( :-(
Where am I wrong?

To=whatsapp:%2B3207633XXX&From=whatsapp:%2B447411256XXX&Body=Put your message body here

Comment: @mauro, correct, you should be able to modify the code to send with your Whatsapp number.

Comment: @Alant thanks, I have updated the image above
i can't get it to work.
How I do the test always tells me:
The request could not be sent to Webhooks by Zapier.
The app returned "A 'To' phone number is required.". :-( :-(
Where am I wrong?